# Why doesn't the action in my code using WhenEvent option of NDSolve work?

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I'm trying to solve two ODEs, and I want to restrict the variables `y1[t]` and `y2[t]` from being less than the constant `ylim` using `WheEvent`. However, I'm wondering why the code below doesn't satisfy this constraint?

I've tried to make Mathematica print some information to confirm if it has indeed captured the event. Based on the results, Mathematica did detect the event, but I'm not sure why it didn't apply the constraint I provided.

Any suggestions?

Thanks :)

[image: y1 and y2]

```
Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;
Ae = 0.0005;
freq = 1;
y0 = 10^5;
ylim = 0.1 y0;
xp[t_] := 0.05 Sin[2 Pi freq t];
up[t_] = D[xp[t], t];
v1[t_] := (0.14 - xp[t]) Ae; 
v2[t_] := (0.14 + xp[t]) Ae;
ode1 = -up[t] Ae + y1'[t] v1[t]/(3 10^8) == -((0.12 0.0008^3)/12 ) (
    y1[t] - y2[t])/0.28;
ode2 =   
  up[t] Ae + y2'[t] v2[t]/(3 10^8) ==   (0.12 0.0008^3)/12  (
    y1[t] - y2[t])/0.28;
sol = First[NDSolve[
    {ode1, ode2
     , y1[0] == y0, y2[0] == y0
     , WhenEvent[y1[t] < ylim, {Print[y1[t]]; y1[t] -> ylim}, 
      "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"]
     , WhenEvent[y2[t] < ylim, {Print[y2[t]]; y2[t] -> ylim}, 
      "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"]
     }, {y1, y2}, {t, 0, 1} 
    ]];
Plot[{y1[t], y2[t], ylim} /. sol, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

=============================== update =======================

With the help of @xzczd and @Daniel Huber, I attempted the following code. Although there was some improvement in `y2`, the results are still not satisfactory.

```
Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;
Ae = 0.0005;
freq = 1;
y0 = 10^5;
ylim = 0.1 y0;
xp[t_] := 0.05 Sin[2 Pi freq t];
up[t_] = D[xp[t], t];
v1[t_] := (0.14 - xp[t]) Ae;
v2[t_] := (0.14 + xp[t]) Ae;

rhs1 = -((0.12 0.0008^3)/12) (y1[t] - y2[t])/0.28;
rhs2 = (0.12 0.0008^3)/12 (y1[t] - y2[t])/0.28
ode1 = -up[t] Ae + y1'[t] v1[t]/(3 10^8) == rhs1;
ode2 = up[t] Ae + y2'[t] v2[t]/(3 10^8) == rhs2;

ode1 = y1'[t] == (rhs1 + up[t] Ae)/(v1[t]/(3 10^8)) onoff1[t];
ode2 = y2'[t] == (rhs2 - up[t] Ae)/(v2[t]/(3 10^8)) onoff2[t];

sol = NDSolve[{ode1, ode2, y1[0] == y0, y2[0] == y0, onoff1[0] == 1, 
    onoff2[0] == 1,
    WhenEvent[y1[t] - ylim < 0 && y1'[t] < 0, {onoff1[t] -> 0}, 
     "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"],
    WhenEvent[y2[t] - ylim < 0 && y2'[t] < 0, {onoff2[t] -> 0}, 
     "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"],
    WhenEvent[(*y1[t]>=ylim||*) y1'[t] >= 0, {onoff1[t] -> 1}, 
     "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"],
    WhenEvent[(*y2[t]>=ylim ||*) y2'[t] >= 0, {onoff2[t] -> 1}, 
     "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"]
    }, {y1, y2, onoff1, onoff2}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   DiscreteVariables -> {onoff1, onoff2}
   , Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"
   (*,Method\[Rule]"BDF"*)
   (*,Method\[Rule]{(*"IndexReduction"\[Rule]{Automatic,
   "IndexGoal"\[Rule]0},*)"EquationSimplification"\[Rule]"Residual"}*)
   ];
Plot[y1[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[y2[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: y1_y2_update1]

Comment: Could you explain what do you try to simulate?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks for your attention, I tried to simulate a toy problem on electro-mechani system. The difference between displacements `y1` and `y2` is governed by a driven motor, but each of them can't be below some limit `ylim`.

Comment: What behavior are you expecting? `y1[t]` or `y2[t]` becomes constant after hitting the limit?

Comment: @xyz Thanks 大神吧主, Without the lower limit constraint ylim, both `y1` and `y2` would roughly follow a sine variation, but with different phases. `y1` would increase from zero, while `y2` would decrease from zero, and so on. Therefore, with this constraint applied, what I expect is that the difference between `y1` and `y2` roughly follows a sine variation, but with both y1 and y2 having a lower limit. It's somewhat like two sine curves with different phases, but both being truncated below by a horizontal line `y = ylim`.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you've misunderstood the usage of `WhenEvent`. Essentially `WhenEvent` is merely for re-initializing the solving process of `NDSolve` i.e. it simply stops the solving process (according to the given condition in 1st argument of `WhenEvent`), set another initial condition (according to 2nd argument of `WhenEvent`) and continue. In other words, it won't change the nature of the ODE system. To achieve what you want, the ODE system itself should be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand what WhenEvent does.

From the manual: "f<0  f crosses zero from below". Here is a simpler example:

```
eq = {f'[x] == 1, f[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[f[x] > 1, Print[{"x=", x, "f[x]", f[x]}]; f[x] -> 1]};
sol = NDSolve[eq, f, {x, 0, 5}][[1]];
Plot[f[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

You see the event only fired once. Namely when f[x] crosses y==1. Then it evaluates the print command and set f[x]=1. However, this does not change anything as f[x] is already 1. In the following steps, f[x] does no more cross y==1, so the event does no more fire.

Comment: Thanks! Then is there a way to tell Mathematica that both `y1[t]` and `y2[t]` can't drop below `ylim`? I tried the following way, but makes no difference.

`WhenEvent[
 y1[t] - ylim < 0 && y1'[t] < 0, {Print[y1[t]]; y1[t] -> ylim}, 
 "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"],
WhenEvent[
 y2[t] - ylim < 0 && y2'[t] < 0, {Print[y2[t]]; y2[t] -> ylim}, 
 "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"]`

Comment: As only the crossing triggers the event, you would have to set y[t] to a value larger than ylim.